# Disappearing Pixels on the edge of Hillshade raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hillshade

When I've created Hillshade in ArcMap and received the output raster, I've noticed that output Hillshade has one pixel less than I have in the source DEM. It doesn't matter where I create it (ArcToolBox or arcpy). Aspect, Slope work fine without that artefacts.

[image]

I've tested this tool on ArcGIS Destop 10.4.1 and 10.6.1. May be somebody know how to solve this problem.

I've tried to do same in QGIS and discovered the option "Compute Edges" in Hillshade dialog (pic below) which solved the problem with edges. Is it possible to do same in ArcGIS (may be in script)? I need to processing a lot of rasters.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour]. This is the expected behaviour. The hillshade algorithm converts four neighbor cells into one, with corners at the previous centers.